# MVC: How to: Clicking on a button without leaving current form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have the following view:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ptiFileName))
{
    <span style="font-style:italic">
        <a href="@Url.Action("DownloadPtiDocument", "Project")" style="text-decoration:underline">@ptiFileName</a>
        <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" href="@Url.Action("DeletePtiDocument", "Project")" type=""></a>
    </span>         
}
```

The controller for **DownloadPtiDocument** is working correctly when user clicks on the filename link:

```
   [Route("project/download/{id:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadPtiDocument(int id)
    {

        var ptiFile = ProjectRepository.GetById(id.ToString()) as Project;

        if (ptiFile.PtiUploadDocuments == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        var info = await S3Helpers.DownloadFile(ptiFile.PtiUploadDocuments.S3Bucket, ptiFile.PtiUploadDocuments.S3FileName);
        if (info != null)
            return new FileStreamResult(info.Stream, info.ContentType) { FileDownloadName = ptiFile.PtiUploadDocuments.FileName };

        return HttpNotFound();
    }
```

But I do not know how to declare the function  **DeletePtiDocument** where the user will stay on the current screen while I perform some logic behind to delete the data from my model.

Here is the interface. Clicking on the icon "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" should perform some action on my controller without refreshing or leaving the current screen. is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Make it an ajax call.

Comment: To make an HTTP request without leaving the current page, it would be an AJAX request made from JavaScript code.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with javascript, if you can point me on the right direction or tutorial that I need to take a look at. It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

yeah definitely it is quite possible by using Ajax do it like this :

```
$('a.glyphicon-trash').click(function(){
    $.post('@Url.Action("DeletePtiDocument","Project")',{//Arguments you want to take there},function(data){
          if(data == "Success")
          {
              //Do whatever you want to do
          }
    });
});
```

Now on Action level, handle it like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeletePtiDocument(arguments which you have passed)
{
    //perform Action
    return Json("Success");
}
```